# how to set VCINSTALLDIR

Tags: visual-studio, npm

I'm trying to install node debug with `npm i ndb --global`, but I get this error:

```
msvs_version was set from command line or npm config
gyp ERR! find VS - looking for Visual Studio version 2019
gyp ERR! find VS VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt
gyp ERR! find VS could not use PowerShell to find Visual Studio 2017 or newer
gyp ERR! find VS looking for Visual Studio 2015
gyp ERR! find VS - not found
gyp ERR! find VS not looking for VS2013 as it is only supported up to Node.js 8
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS valid versions for msvs_version:
gyp ERR! find VS
gyp ERR! find VS **************************************************************
gyp ERR! find VS You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio
gyp ERR! find VS including the "Desktop development with C++" workload.
gyp ERR! find VS For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find VS https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows
gyp ERR! find VS ***********************
```

I have Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition with desktop development with c++ workload installed. And early I already set the msvs_version like this: `npm config set msvs_version=2019`

So, the question is, how to set the VCINSTALLDIR variable?

Comment: `VCINSTALLDIR not set, not running in VS Command Prompt` Use the [developer command prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/command-prompt-powershell?view=vs-2019#developer-command-prompt).

Answer (score 0):

Try opening a command prompt in Visualo Studio.  Run `SET VSIN` to get the current value of the variable.  In my case:

`VSINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\`

Use GUI or Comand line to set the variable.  Note, you have to use " marks becuase of spaces in the path.  Then because it ends in a slash you need to escape the last slash or it picks up the final " as part of the variable.

`SETX VSINSTALLDIR C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\"

now repoen the terminal where you are running `npm ...` and you should see the variable is set.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and spent hours trying to fix this. For me, the problem was the version of node used. The node I used had an internal version of node-gyp that was very old (version 5.1.0) and is NOT compatible with Visual Studio 2022.
There are two ways to resolve this:

1. Use a more advanced version of node (I tried node 16.0.0 and above and they all worked for me). Versions 14.17.5 and below didn't work for me.
2. If you can't upgrade your version of node due to dependency issues, then updating your node-gyp globally won't work and you must update it internally within the location where you node version is installed. It is not complicated. Follow the instructions here: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/blob/main/docs/Updating-npm-bundled-node-gyp.md
   Note: Using the instructions in this link - I tried installing the latest version of node-gyp and it caused new problems. So I tried using node-gyp version 9.0.0 and that worked for me.